# Changing the String array for JComboBox

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

In my program I have a reader that finds all the files under a certain folder - converts the name of the folder into a string - stores it in a string array (String [] test)

Then I set this array in JComboBox(test);

I want to be able to set a new String[] to the same JComboBox at some point of time in the program instead of creating a new JComboBox.

How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: comboBoxName.set...

Comment: [Set a new model.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setModel%28javax.swing.ComboBoxModel%29)

Comment: Bakero98, name.set doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this one:**

```
String test[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(test);
JComboBox.setModel(model);
```

for more details, maybe you can visit [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/javax.swing/JComboBox/1500__JComboBox.setModel_ComboBoxModel_lt_E_gt_aModel_.htm)

cheers :)